# How to replace a character in a multiline string with a variable

Tags: python, string

I have a multiline string containing the ascii art of a playing card:

```
clubs_ascii = """
             _____
            |V .  | 
            | /.\ |
            |(_._)|
            |  |  |
            |____V|
        """
```

I try to replace the letter "V" (V for value) with a randomly genererated number, say 4, using replace:

```
clubs_ascii.replace("V", random_number)
```

The result is always unchanged

```
             _____
            |V .  | 
            | /.\ |
            |(_._)|
            |  |  |
            |____V|
```

Why is this and how can i get it to function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `replace` *computes* & *returns* a new string; it does not modify the string it is called on.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to set the `clubs_ascii` variable equal to `clubs_ascii.replace("V", random_number)`, due to the fact that, as pointed out in the comments, replace computes & returns a new string; it does not modify the string it is called on.